# What kind of floor tile is this?

Tags: flooring

I'm trying to determine this type of common floor tile covering. Can anyone help me identify?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called VCT, Vinyl Composition tile.  It's normally installed with adhesive and maintained with various cleaners and polishes.  It's very common in commercial installations.

Comment: It can be repeatedly stripped and refinished since it's a solid, full-thickness material.

Comment: In some cases the tiles are actually possible to remove one by one. "Computer flooring" as we used to call it - you can run wires below the floor, and the tiles facilitate access if necessary. But you can also lay them as a regular floor.

Comment: @StianYttervik, Yep, you're talking about a [Raised Floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_floor) or Access Floor.  VCT is common, but I've also seen carpet tiles installed on them and some other options.  VCT is just so resilient and easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

Vinyl tile. They have sticky stuff on back, they put it down and if someone damages it, they peel off and stick another one. Same with carpet tiles. Fun stuff!